# how to add login to localdb connection

Tags: sql, localdb

I recently upgraded to a windows 10 virtual machine and copied over a web/domain Entity Framework project I've been working on.

Problem is, now that my windows username has changed I no longer have access to the (localdb)/v11.0 database instance the domain project uses. When I try to connect from server explorer in Visual Studio, it says my current windows login doesn't have permission.

Just wondering how can I gain access to this database in order to add a user (will sql admin work?), ideally I'd like to do it from command line or visual studio. I don't want to have to install sql management studio if I don't have to.

Let me know your thoughts, I'm not the savviest when it comes to database management and such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very good answer. But i did nothing and eventually after rebuilding and closing the project and re-opening I was able to gain access to the LocalDB project in server explorer. The tables where visible but the data was missing. I just ended up inserting the data into the tables again because I had pre-canned scripts ready as it was.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has to do with Windows access rights, not with database user rights.

Are you able to see your database in the "SQL Server Object Explorer" (not "Server Explorer") window? On my system I find my local db there under the tree node "SQL Server/(localdb)v.11/Databases.

Then you can right click and choose "Properties" to the properties of the database. Among the properties there is the "Data File" setting.
On my system it points to

**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\NAME_OF_DATABASE.mdf**

On your system it could be at the same location. (Or search for the mdf file with an admin user).

You could then login with an admin user, extract the file and copy it to a folder your new user has control over. Then take ownership of the file via Windows Explorer and set full access rights too.

Finally you can reconnect to the mdf file with Visual studio "Server Explorer" like in the video [shown here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDLQPD2AV_E) (it uses an older version of Visual Studio, but the steps are similar in VS 2013).